# IndexError: list index out of range - Quiz

Tags: python

I am writing a spanish quiz in python, and I am running into a problem when the user inputs an incorrect answer in the quiz.

```
import random

def create_dictionary(filename):
   dictionary = {} 

   file = open(filename)  
   for line in file:

       line = line.replace('\n','')

       split = line.split(':') 
       spanish_words = split[1].split(',')
       dictionary[split[0]] = spanish_words 

   file.close()
   return dictionary

def main():

   dictionary = create_dictionary('project13_data.txt')

   print (dictionary)

   questions = int(input("How many questions do you want to be quizzed on? "))
   final = questions
   wrong = []

   while questions > 0:

       def good_guess():
           if val == answer[0] or answer[1]: 
               print("Correct\n")
           else:
               print("Wrong\n")
               wrong.append(find)


    find = random.choice(list(dictionary.keys()))
    answer = dictionary[find][0:2]

       print(find)
       print(answer)

       print("What is" ,find, "in spanish? ")
       val = input("Answer: ")
       good_guess() 

       questions = questions - 1

   print("You got", len(wrong), "wrong out of", final)
   print(list(wrong))
main()
```

The error that i am getting is

`File "C:\Python34\Project 13 take 2.py", line 33, in good_guess
    if val == answer[0] or answer[1]:
    IndexError: list index out of range`

If the user inputs a correct answer, the code runs fine, but otherwise I get the error. I do not know why I am getting this error, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: have you search `IndexError: list index out of range` in google or SO?

Comment: The error says exactly what's wrong. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: Aside from the error you're getting, you'll probably also want to look more into `if val == answer[0] or answer[1]`.  This doesn't behave as I'm imagining you expect it would.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your immediate problem is that **answer** is not defined when you get to that line of code.  Neither is **find**, a few lines below.  Those variables are in an outer scope.  You should pass them into the function as arguments.

You may have a problem with redefining the built-in names, **split** and **file** as local variables.

Why do you redefine the function **good_guess** every time thorough your *while* loop?  I think this should be placed at the top of **main**, or perhaps before it -- if you've set up answer and find as parameters.

BTW, your use of **answer[0]** is legal in Python 2.7.

Answer (score -1):

Unrelated to your error, `if val == answer[0] or answer[1]:` doesn't work this way.

Python will evaluate `val == answer[0]` and will return `True` or `False`. Depending on what value it gets it will then evaluate `bool(answer[1])` which will return `False` if it's an empty string, an empty list or 0, and `True` otherwise.

Instead, use `if val == answer[0] or val == answer[1]` or better:
`if val in [answer[0], answer[1]]:`.